# Media query to detect laggy position: fixed behaviour

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a website with some elements that have `position: fixed`. It looks fine on a desktop browser, but on my phone (Xperia Arc, Android 2.3) those elements scroll with the page until you release your finger from the screen, at which point they'll jump to their proper location. This looks ugly.

Now, I could easily change the CSS so the site also looks fine on devices with this behaviour, but can such behaviour (or a correlated property) be detected with a CSS media query?

Answer (score 1):

CSS media queries do not detect behaviour. They detect:

- width and height of the browser window
- device width and height
- orientation – landscape/portrait mode
- resolution

More info: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media1

Answer (score 0):

add this meta element and this css.

meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /

body {
      -webkit-user-select:none;
      -webkit-touch-callout:none;
      -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

try that. but i can't test it so i duno